# Initializing a pydantic dataclass from json

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, pydantic

I'm in the process of converting existing `dataclasses` in my project to `pydantic-dataclasses`, I'm using these `dataclasses` to represent models I need to both encode-to and parse-from json.

Here's an example of my current approach that is not good enough for my use case, I have a class `A` that I want to both convert into a dict (to later be converted written as json) and to read from that dict.
But the only way I can find to parse the json back into a model gives me back the underlying `BaseModel` and not the `dataclass`.

note that I'm using the `asdict` function to convert the `dataclass` to a `dict` as it's what the `pydantic_encoder` uses to convert the `dataclass` to json, and using the `pydantic_encoder` what the documentation recommends to convert a `pydantic-dataclass` to json:
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/

```py
from dataclasses import asdict
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import BaseModel

@dataclass
class A:
    x: str

a = A("string")
a_dict = asdict(a)
parsed_a = A.__pydantic_model__.parse_obj(a_dict)

print(f"type of a: {type(a)}")
print(f"type of parsed_a: {type(parsed_a)}")

print(f"a is instance of A: {isinstance(a, A)}")
print(f"parsed_a is instance of A: {isinstance(parsed_a, A)}")

print(f"a is instance of BaseModel: {isinstance(a, BaseModel)}")
print(f"parsed_a is instance of BaseModel: {isinstance(parsed_a, BaseModel)}")
```

output:

```
type of a: <class '__main__.A'>
type of parsed_a: <class '__main__.A'>
a is instance of A: True
parsed_a is instance of A: False
a is instance of BaseModel: False
parsed_a is instance of BaseModel: True
```

Is there maybe a way to initialize `A` from the parsed `BaseModel`?

Comment: There should be a `from_json()` `classmethod` for `BaseModel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on others' answers, since the right/best answer to this appears to constantly change:

Using Pydantic's `TypeAdapter` is currently the way to go. Updated @pceccon example:

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import TypeAdapter
import dataclasses
import json

@dataclass
class User:
  id: int
  name: str

user = User(id=123, name="James")
user_json = json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(user))
print(user_json)  # '{"id": 123, "name": "James"}'

user = TypeAdapter(User).validate_json(user_json)
print(user)  # User(id=123, name='James')
print(user.name)  # 'James'
```

if you want PyCharm (or whatever editor) to give you autocompletion/intellisense, use a type hint:

```py
user: User = TypeAdapter(User).validate_json(user_json)
```

if you have a dictionary instead of json, you can use `TypeAdapter.validate_python` instead:

```py
user: User = TypeAdapter(User).validate_python(user_dict)
```

This works recursively for your model/class definitions.

Answer (score 26):

I think I arrive a little bit late to the party, but I think this answer may come handy for future users having the same question.

To convert the `dataclass` to json you can use the combination that you are already using using (`asdict` plus `json.dump`).

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User:
  id: int
  name: str

user = User(id=123, name="James")
d = asdict(user)  # {'id': 123, 'name': 'James'
user_json = json.dumps(d)
print(user_json)  # '{"id": 123, "name": "James"}'

# Or directly with pydantic_encoder
json.dumps(user, default=pydantic_encoder)
```

Then from the raw `json` you can use a `BaseModel` and the `parse_raw` method.

If you want to deserialize json into `pydantic` instances, I recommend you using the `parse_raw` method:

```py
user = User.__pydantic_model__.parse_raw('{"id": 123, "name": "James"}')
print(user)
# id=123 name='James'
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep the dataclass:

```py
json_raw = '{"id": 123, "name": "James"}'
user_dict = json.loads(json_raw)
user = User(**user_dict)
```

Comment: does the parsing work recursively?

Comment: Why not just `User.parse_raw('{"id": 123, "name": "James"}')`

Comment: Because pydantic dataclass do not have access to this method directly. You first have to pick the BaseModel using the `__pydandic_model__` attribute

Comment: In Pydantic 2, it looks like we need `User.__pydantic_validator__.validate_json(json_str)`

Answer (score 11):

Now it's possible to solve this issue in a simple manner, in my opinion.
Adding to @Guillem example:

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic.tools import parse_obj_as
import dataclasses
import json

@dataclass
class User:
  id: int
  name: str

user = User(id=123, name="James")
user_json = json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(user))
print(user_json)  # '{"id": 123, "name": "James"}'

user_dict = json.loads(user_json)
user = parse_obj_as(User, user_dict)
print(user)  # User(id=123, name='James')
```

It works for recursively as well.

Comment: `parse_obj_as` is deprecated as of Pydantic v2 https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/

Comment: The penultimate line becomes `user =TypeAdapter(User).validate_python(user_dict)` if you made it this far.

Answer (score 10):

Pydantic [recommends](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation) using `parse_raw` to deserialize JSON strings.

### Class definition

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ResponseData(BaseModel):
    status_code: int
    text: str
    reason: str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

### JSON to BaseModel conversion

```
x = ResponseData(status_code=200, text="", reason="")
json = x.json()
response = ResponseData.parse_raw(json)
assert x == response
print(response.dict())
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this is the current recommended method, as of February 2023: https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation

Comment: This only works when your classes inherit from `BaseModel` not when using the @dataclass decorator. https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/dataclasses/

Comment: Update for January 2024: parse_raw() has been deprecated and you are now to use model_validate_json(). Reference: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/

Answer (score 2):

I managed to address this issue by unpacking the properties of the parsed `BaseModel` and initializing the `dataclass` with them.

this solution works recursively for Pydantic dataclasses whose properties are either pydantic-dataclasses or primitives

please note that this solution doesn't work for for Unions and Generics (yet).

```py
 def pydantic_dataclass_from_json_dict(json_dict: dict, pydantic_dataclass_type) -> Any:
    base_model = pydantic_dataclass_type.__pydantic_model__.parse_obj(json_dict)
    base_mode_fields = base_model.__fields__
    dataclass_fields = dataclasses.fields(pydantic_dataclass_type)

    values = []
    for base_model_field_name, base_model_field in base_mode_fields.items():
        value = getattr(base_model, base_model_field_name)
        dataclass_field = [field for field in dataclass_fields if field.name == base_model_field.name][0]
        if is_dataclass(dataclass_field):
            converted_value = pydantic_dataclass_from_json_dict(value, dataclass_field.type)
            values.append(converted_value)
        else:
            values.append(value)

    dataclass_object = pydantic_dataclass_type(*values)
    return dataclass_object
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried the above ways but it's error because **pydantic_model** is not existing BaseModel attribute.

So I checked functions in the class model.
I found 'parse_raw()' in it and tried instead the above ways
It's good working

Let use parse_raw() function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).